# Max count on group by - Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I have following two tables:

```
1.) Articles - [ArticleID]
2.) ArticleComments - [CommentID], [ArticleID]
```

I want to retrieve ArticleID with maximum no. of comments e.g.

```
ArticleID - 2
TotalNoOfComments - 15
```

How do I do it in Entity Framework?

I access ArticleComments collection like following: article.ArticleComments. The following will be the object to store the result.

```
public class CommentStats
{
    public int ContextId { get; set; }
    public int CommentCount { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var query = context.Articles.
            Select(a => new CommentStats
                                    {
                                        ContextId = a.Id,
                                        CommentCount = a.ArticleComments.Count
                                    }
                  ).OrderByDescending(cs => cs.commentCount);
```

You can then run `FirstOrDefault` for the one article with most comments, or `ToList` for the whole ordered list.

Comment: Even following worked equally well...

public udMostCommented GetMostCommented()
{
var comments = (this.Fetch().GroupBy(x => x.ContextId).OrderByDescending(x => x.Max(y => x.Count())).FirstOrDefault());

            udMostCommented mostCommented = new udMostCommented
            {
                ContextID = comments.FirstOrDefault().ContextId,
                NumberOfComments = comments.Count()
            };

            return mostCommented;
}

Thanks, anyways.